# How to detect a-z letters in php loop?

Tags: php, sorting, loops

I want to detect starting letter of string A-Z

Currently I am displaying data using loop which displays data from **a to z**

Now I want to detect data starting with letter **"a"** in loop

Is that possible using PHP?

I want same this http://cdn.ihwy.net/ihwy-com/labs/demos/jquery-listnav.html using PHP

Actually I want to add "Clear" name class after printing "a" letter data and so on for every letter (b,c,d.....z)

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Where did the upvote come from? This question is quite low quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if all of the categories are stored in an array

```
//Define the first letter that you want to focus on
$letter = 'b';

//Store all items in an array
$categories = array('Books', 'Marketing', 'TV', 'Radio', 'Computers');

//Loop thru
for($i=0;$i<count($categories);$i++)
{
    //This might be case sensitive, so lower the items and get the first letter of it
    if(strtolower(substr($categories[$i], 0, 1)) == $letter)
    {
         echo $categories[$i].'<br />';
    }
}
```

OR, if you're storing all of them in MySQL

```
//Connect to MySQL
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
//Query the DB for all categories beginnng with a particular letter
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category LIKE '".$letter."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $categories[$i] = $row['category'];

  $i++;
}

//Loop thru
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
   echo $categories[$i].'<br />';
}
```

You produce the exact same effect that's shown on the link you provided, you'll need more than just PHP; you'll need JS too. But, that's another task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are several ways, a really simple one is to just check the first letter in the string:

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if($line[0] == "a") {
        echo $line
    }
}
```

If you want to be a bit more fancy you can do the same by using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(preg_match("/^a.*/", $line) {
        echo $line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a storage engine like MySQL you should sort the data before the results, e.g:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'a%'
```

If you are using memory you probably want to use some sort of a filter function:

```
$a = [];
foreach ($data as $i => $v)
    if ($v{0} == "a") $a[] $v;

// $a now contains everything on a*
```

Sorting the results:

```
natsort($a);
```